# LibGDX - why isn't their a create() method on "implements screen"?

Tags: libgdx

When I had the application listener their was a create method but now their isn't. And I need the create() method to continue with my app. Currently, I have a main menu screen and I need a stage and such to get button and other things to appear but I need the create() method. Can someone explain this to me please?

Comment: Just use the constructor as your create method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ApplicationListener` needs a `create()` method because at construction time resources like OpenGL might not be initialised, `create()` is called once Libgdx is actually initialised.

Typically you would create your `Screen` objects from `ApplicationListener.create()` so you can simply use their constructors to initialise whatever you need.

There is no need for a `create()` method in `Screen`.